# Error 500 after installing of phpmyadmin on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Error after installing of phpmyadmin on ubuntu 16.04.

Install:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf
sudo a2enconf phpmyadmin
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Error in /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/usr/share/php/php-gettext/gettext.inc' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/select_lang.lib.php on line 477
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php:0
PHP   2. require_once() /usr/share/phpmyadmin/index.php:12
PHP   3. require() /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/common.inc.php:569
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install php-gettext
```

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted if you found solution yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This was reported as a bug last month. The solution give is to run the command below.

```
apt-get install php-mbstring php7.0-mbstring php-gettext
```

Bug: [PHPMyAdmin requires mbstring](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/phpmyadmin/+bug/1577482)